# secondary hard drive sometimes mounted to wrong location?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, automount

So i edited the `/etc/fstab` file, and added this line

```
/dev/sdb1       /media/additionaldrive1 ext4 defaults   0       2
```

and most times, my hard drive is there waiting for me in the right location. but sometimes, and I'm not sure if i'ts at boot up, or sometimes afterwards, since I generally don't need to the use the drive immediately after boot up, I find the drive not at `/media/addtionaldrive1`, but at some seemingly random address of "62ae4915-ee29-414e-a684-fc700064d952"

This is annoying as it breaks file references to that drive (it has my virtual machine images). Any idea what the problem is? Reboot generally solves, it's not a very nice solution though.

edit:here is the fstab file:

```
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/sda1       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/dev/sda5       none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sdb1       /media/additionaldrive1 ext4 defaults   0       2
```

Comment: Is it an internal HDD? Do you see any references to the drive in the logs (`/var/log/syslog` for example)?

Comment: Could you please include the whole content of your `/etc/fstab`. Also, what's wrong with using the standard `/etc/fstab`, with UUIDs (that seem more robust than paths), that Ubuntu creates on an install?

Comment: i see lines like this:
Aug 15 17:30:49 mymachine kernel: [   23.230331] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
and
Aug 15 17:30:49 mymachine kernel: [   33.264252] EXT4-fs (sdb1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

Comment: i edited the question with fstab file as well, N.N., could you elaborate on your suggestion, new to ubuntu here, what are saying I should change?

Comment: ah, i think im making progress, i started reading this again (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions) and i noticed that there was an additional drive being mounted... my android phone! when i usually have it plugged in to charge, etc. with the usb. anyways, starting up without it plugged in has solved the problem, i will try the uuid path approach, please suggest that as a solution so i can mark as answered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prevent this from happening by using UUID in place of device paths.

Your fstab should look something like

```
    # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=60db2d35-5065-476c-9396-92e8754dd613 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=66d44124-3c90-4e42-8d1a-eb8f84350b4b /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=4bd642b2-bff1-42cf-a013-f30c592cadc9 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

You can find out details at 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

and a guide on how to set this up at 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-finding-using-uuids-to-update-fstab/